# CSV creating new lines when it shouldn't

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm currently working on a project for myself, and that includes scraping [this specific website.](https://www.kickante.com.br)

My code currently looks like this:

```
for i in range(0,4):
my_url = 'https://www.kickante.com.br/campanhas-crowdfunding?page='+str(i)
uclient = ureq(my_url)
page_html = uclient.read()
uclient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')

containers = page_soup.find_all("div", {"class":"campaign-card-wrapper views-row"})
for container in containers:
    #Achando os títulos das campanhas
    titleCampaignBruto = container.div.div.a.img["title"].replace('Crowdfunding para: ', '')
    titleCampaignParsed = titleCampaignBruto.strip().replace(",", ";")
    #Achando o valor da campanha
    arrecadadoFind = container.div.find_all("div",{"class":"funding-raised"})
    arrecadado = arrecadadoFind[0].text.strip().replace(",", ".")

    #Número de doadores
    doadoresBruto = container.div.find_all('span', {"class":"contributors-value"})
    doadoresParsed = doadoresBruto[0].text.strip().replace(",",";")

    #target da campanha
    fundingGoal = container.div.find_all('div', {"class":"funding-progress"})
    quantoArrecadado = fundingGoal[0].text.strip().replace(",",";")

    #Descricao da campanha
    descricaoBruta = container.div.find_all('div', {"class":"field field-name-field-short-description field-type-text-long field-label-hidden"})
    descricaoParsed = descricaoBruta[0].text.strip().replace(",",";")

    #link da campanha
    linkCampanha = container.div.find_all('href')
    print("Título da campanha: " + titleCampaignParsed)
    print("Valor da campanha: " +arrecadado)
    print("Doadores: "+ doadoresParsed)
    print("target: " + quantoArrecadado)
    print("descricao: " + descricaoParsed)

    f.write(titleCampaignParsed + "," + arrecadado + "," + doadoresParsed + "," + quantoArrecadado+ "," + descricaoParsed.replace("," ,";") + "\n")
i = i+1
f.close()
```

When I open the csv file it generated, I see that some lines are broken where they shouldn't be (example: [See line 31 on the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irLuq.png)). That line should be a part of the previous line (line 30) as the body of the description.

Does anyone have an idea of what can be causing that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The example you linked doesn't have a line 32.

Comment: Line 31, my bad. That line is part of the description column of the previous line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the text you're writing to CSV might contain newlines. You can remove them like so:

```py
csv_line_entries = [
    titleCampaignParsed, arrecadado,  doadoresParsed, 
    quantoArrecadado, descricaoParsed.replace("," ,";")
]
csv_line = ','.join([
    entry.replace('\n', ' ') for entry in csv_line_entries
])
f.write(csv_line + '\n')
```

## Cause of the bug

The `strip()` method removes only leading and trailing newlines/whitespace.

```py
import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<p>Whatever\nelse\n</p>')
soup.find('p').text.strip()
>>> 'Whatever\nelse'
```

Notice that the inner `\n` is not removed.

Comment: I thought the .strip() method removed those, no?

Comment: @MauricioSouza I guess that's the root of your problem. `strip()` removes only _leading and trailing_ newlines and whitespace.

Comment: Ohhhh, geez. Thank you so so much! Sorry for bothering with such simple problem.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have newlines in the middle of the text. `strip()` only removes whitespace on the start and end of a string, so you need to use `replace('\n','')` instead. This replaces all of the newlines `\n` with nothing `''`

Comment: Ohh, I see. Thank you so so much! Sorry for bothering with as simple problem.